# Merging git branches when one has a revert that the other doesn't want

Tags: git, git-merge

We're working on two releases, a minor one and a major one, each with their own `git` branch. A feature was added originally to the minor branch before we created the major branch. Later that feature was removed from the minor branch (with a `revert` commit) because we decided to introduce the feature in the major release.

So now we have a situation where if we merge the changes from the minor branch into the major branch, it will include the revert commit, which doesn't make sense in the major branch.

One option I've considered is to use `cherry-pick` on the commits in the minor branch after the revert commit, but this has the disadvantage that any branches based on the minor branch won't be merge-able with the major branch. (We'd have to continue using `cherry-pick` for anything like that.) It has the advantage, though, of a more accurate history since the revert commit won't be included.

The other option is to merge all of the minor branch into the major branch and just "ignore" the revert changes. By "ignore", I mean to manually revert the reverted changes when doing the merge. This preserves the history better from git's point of view, but might mean some untangling during the merge.

Generally we've only used merges in the main branches, and cherry-picking only to adjust fixes to the latest code before they're merged. So my preference is to go with the second option, but I wanted to find out here if that's the proper way to deal with this situation, or if there's something I'm missing.

EDIT: Here's the ASCII-art :-)

```
*   (major)
| * (minor)
* | ...
| * revert feature on minor
* | major: unrelated commit
| * minor: unrelated commit
* |
|/
*   common ancestor
|
*   add feature to main branch
```

Comment: You question is missing ASCII-Art :). Did you revert a commit that was only on the minor branch or was that commit created in the major branch before the branch of or merged into the minor branch?

Comment: And was the minor branch merged to the major branch after the feature was added to the minor branch but before the revert was added to the minor branch?

Comment: I wasn't clear that the feature commit is common on both branches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm curious about what you mean by, "doesn't make sense in the major branch."  Are you concerned that the feature will be reverted on the major branch?  Or are you just annoyed that a commit titled something like "revert feature" will appear in the history of the major branch when in fact the feature is there?

It's hard to say what the result of merging will be without more details, but here are some possibilities:

If your history looks something like this:

```
*   (major)
| * (minor)
* |
| * revert feature on minor
* | cherry-pick feature onto major
| * add feature to minor
* |
|/
*   common ancestor
|
```

Then you can simply merge `minor` into `major` without any problems.

Why?  Think of it this way:  When you merge `minor` into `major`, you are effectively taking the diff between the common ancestor (`git merge-base major minor`) and `minor`, applying it as a patch onto `major`, and then creating a commit that happens to have both `major` and `minor` as parents.

The diff between the common ancestor and `minor` would not contain any hint of the feature that was added and then reverted because the two commits cancel each other out.  Thus, the only changes that would be introduced into `major` would be changes caused by the other commits on `minor`.

If your history looks like this:

```
*   (major)
| * (minor)
* |
| * revert feature on minor
* | merge minor into major
|\|
* | cherry-pick feature onto major
| * add feature to minor
* |
|/
*
|
```

Then you have a problem.  In this case, the common ancestor between `major` and `minor` is the commit labeled "`add feature to minor`".  If you look at the diff between this common ancestor and `minor`, the diff will include the revert of the feature.  When you merge `minor` into `major`, this diff will be applied to `major`, reverting the feature on `major`.

In this case, there are a couple of simple ways you can avoid losing the feature on `major`:

- Merge `minor` into `major`, then revert the revert.  The resulting graph would look like this:

  ```
  *   revert the revert (major)
  |
  *   merge minor into major
  |\
  * |
  | * (minor)
  * |
  | * revert feature on minor
  * | merge minor into major
  |\|
  * | cherry-pick feature onto major
  | * add feature to minor
  * |
  |/
  *
  |
  ```
- Create a new branch off of `minor`.  Let's call it `minor-for-merge`.  On this branch, revert the revert.  Then merge the branch to `major` and delete the branch.  The resulting graph would look like this:

  ```
  *     merge minor-for-merge into major (major)
  |\
  | *   revert the revert
  *  \
  |   * (minor)
  *   |
  |   * revert feature on minor
  *   | merge minor into major
  |\_ |
  *  \| cherry-pick feature onto major
  |   * add feature to minor
  * _/
  |/
  *
  |
  ```

Either way works.  The latter is a bit awkward—the commit reverting the revert is sort of dangling off in no-man's land—but it can help you avoid lots of merge conflicts when merging to `major`.

Either way you go, any branches off of `minor` will be mergeable to `major` without reverting the feature.  If a branch off of `minor` was made before the revert, then the revert won't be in the history being merged in.  If the branch off of `minor` was made after the revert (or if `minor` was merged into the branch after the revert), then the revert still won't be in the history being merged in because that commit is already in `major`'s ancestry.

Comment: Actually your second scenario is similar to what I have. I like the idea of a revert-the-revert commit before the merge. I'll try that and see how it works. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: So I reverted the revert commit before merging. It worked flawlessly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can merge the minor branch and 'revert the revert', I mean

```
git merge <minor branch>
git revert <revert commit>
```

also check this '[How to Revert Faulty Merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)', it is not about your problem exactly but you can have some idea about the effect of 'revert a revert'.

Comment: @MichaelBest You are welcome :) I'm pleased that Richard Hansen presented an excellent answer which explained what I can't for my poor English.